# I want to print the length of the list to the first duplicate?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have created a function answer here and what I exactly want to do is print the count until the list has unique values.

What I did is:
Step 1: I passed a number x into a function.
Step 2: Created x and y which is nothing but ascending and descending values of x.
step 3: I did z= x-y and assigned z to n which is the new value of n
Step 4: Repeat and store values in a list until the list is unique.

For example: if n = 1211 then x = 2111 and y = 1112 therefore z= 2111-1112 = 0999  now next n= 0999 .

1. Now list is [1211, 0999]
2. This will go on till the list has unique value

I know that something is wrong with my answer function because what it is doing is just removing duplicate values from the list and printing it.
Now it is running an infinite loop but shouldn't because the answer is 1, it repeats after one value.
Can you tell me to how to improve my code so that I can get the count right?

```
def dscend(n):
    listb = map(int, str(n))
    b = sorted(listb, key=int, reverse=False)
    asc = int(''.join(map(str, b)))
    return asc

def ascend(n):
    lista = map(int, str(n))
    a = sorted(lista, key=int, reverse=True)
    dsc = int(''.join(map(str, a)))
    return dsc


def answer(n):
    nums = []
    n = int(n)
    while n not in nums[:n]:
        final = nums.append(n)
        w = len(nums)
        x = ascend(n)
        y = dscend(n)
        z = x - y
        n = z
        print w
        print nums


answer("1211")
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want? Do you want to count the number of unique elements, or of duplicates, or the length of the list to the first duplicate, or the length of the list from the last duplicate? Please re-word, to make it clearer.

Comment: length to the list to the first duplicate. @JohanL

Comment: How does `n not in nums[:n]:` work exactly? You want to slice the list from the start to the 1211 index of a starting empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (main) issues with your code. First, you must check the full list of noms, to ensure you have no duplicates, not a slice up to `n`, where `n` is a rather arbitrary number. In addition, you also need to keep your list entries as strings, to ensure that you represent `'0999'` as such and not as `999`. With this change `ascend` and `descend` does not need to turn the input into strings, but instead the result must be converted to a string with leading zeros.

In addition, if you want to find the cycle length of the repeating pattern, you have to add a few lines at the end, where you use the found duplicate as search value into your original list, to find the first element of the cycle.

Thus, with these changes the code look like, where the final print is from the cycle:

```
def descend(n):
    listb = map(int, n)
    b = sorted(listb, key=int, reverse=False)
    asc = int(''.join(map(str, b)))
    return asc

def ascend(n):
    lista = map(int, n)
    a = sorted(lista, key=int, reverse=True)
    dsc = int(''.join(map(str, a)))
    return dsc

def answer(n):
    n_len = len(n)
    nums = []
    while n not in nums:
        final = nums.append(n)
        w = len(nums)
        x = ascend(n)
        y = descend(n)
        z = x - y
        n = "{:0{n_len}}".format(z, n_len=n_len)
        print w
        print nums
    first = nums.index(n)
    nums = nums[first:]
    w = len(nums)
    print w
    print nums

answer("1211")
```

I hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking except for their is one small issue if you could address that if would be grateful to you.  At some point n = 6174 and then z = 7641 - 1467 which is nothing but 6714 and it is recursive after this point . So is their any way i can count this cycle and print the count which is 1 in this case

Comment: Well, that just works, doesn't it? When I test `answer('6174')` I get the printouts `1` and `['6174']`.

Comment: I want to do that because for this particular number this cycle is small i.e 6714 comes to 6714 in just one iteration so the list has ('6714'). But for some case this cycle can be big. So is their any way i could find this cycle

Comment: Yeah it works but suppose i want to find this 6174 cycle by entering "1211" in the answer function.

Comment: Yes, but that also works. The last entry in the `nums` must be a value that just repeats as itself or the sequence would continue.

Comment: You are missing my point here: Suppose we have n = 210022 in base 3. When calculations are done in base 3 it would at some point give [210111,122221,102212] and this cycle repeats so the count is 3 here. Simillary it i take some number other than 1211 in  base 10 their will be some case where such cycle happens. So i there any possible way i could do that.

Comment: You see in this cycle we knew 6174 would give 1 but then it will not be the case with each number

Comment: I tried doing n= 210022 in base 3 it gives [210022,220101,210111,122221,102212,210111]. You see this cycle the 210111 repeats itself. So by your code the len should be 6 . But i only want 3 as the cycle repeats itself by 3

Comment: Ah, I see. OK, that would require a small change. I think the simplest way to handle it, is to continue counting, but backwards, until we hit upon the same value once more, or, perhaps simpler, find the first occurrence of the repeated value.

Comment: Yeah , But what i was thinking  was that i can get that repeating no. after the second last iteration and before the last iteration. So I can  take that no. insert in list again and find the difference between the indexes. I guess that would work. I the mean mean time if your solution can get me a better solution then its good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147573/discussion-between-johanl-and-dr-duck).